# Get-ChildItem Exclude and File parameters don't work together

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I can't figure out why these two parameters of the Get-ChildItem cmdlet don't work together. To make my question as clear as possible, look at the following example. From the Powershell ISE command pane:

- Type 'dir'  -->  All files and sub-folders in the current directory are displayed.
- Type 'dir -File'  -->  Original list minus sub-folders is displayed.
- Type 'dir -Exclude "*.txt"'  -->  Original list minus .txt files is displayed.
- Type 'dir -File -Exclude "*.txt"' -->  NOTHING is displayed.

I would expect the original list minus sub-folders and .txt files. But regardless of what argument I use for '-Exclude', I get no items listed.
I have looked at the Get-ChildItem -full documentation, and the related articles here (Stack Overflow) and at other reliable resources, and still don't understand why this fails. Even the classic "-Include '*.txt' -Exclude 'A*'" example fails when you add "-File". How can I use -File and -Exclude together?

Comment: You need `Get-ChildItem * -File -Exclude *.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Whilst dir is an alias for `Get-ChildItem`, I find it best to use the full cmdlets when providing answers.

To use proper PowerShell cmdlets it would be best for you to use the following:

```
Get-ChildItem * -Exclude "*.txt" -File
```

What you see above is the PowerShell cmdlet to get all items in the path specified (using the `*` assumes you want all items from the current location)

You can also use `-Path` and provide the location of the path to where you want to get the items as well, such as:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Path\Folder" -Exclude "*.txt" -File
```