# Get-ChildItem with exclude parameter on root directory doesn't work. Why?

Tags: powershell

I'm new to really using powershell, and just stumbled onto this. I can do

`Get-ChildItem c:\windows -exclude Temp`

and it works just fine. But running the same command on a root directory (e.g. `c:\`, `d:\`) will return nothing.

`Get-ChildItem c:\ -exclude Temp`

When I ran into this, I was baffled. At least one person has reported it as a "[bug](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/11088852-exclude-parameter-doesn-t-work-on-get-childitem-l)". My question is - is it really? Or is there some explanation for why this is "correct" behavior?

In searching for info on this problem, there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43191453/get-childitem-exclude-and-file-parameters-dont-work-together) where we find out `-include` is subtly different than `-exclude` in how it applies - though maybe it is at the root (no pun intended) of why the `-exclude` behavior is different for root directories?

I can work around the problem in several different ways. I was just hoping someone who understands powershell thoroughly might shed some light on if the behavior of `-exclude` on root directories really is a bug, or is somehow correct.

Comment: `Exclude` has too many inconsistencies and I personally usually just filter with `Where-Object`

Comment: Just one of many misleading and untrustworthy PowerShell features, better get used to them now. For more fun, consider `Get-ChildItem C:\* -Exclude Temp` and see what that does. Then try `Get-Item C:\* -Exclude Temp` which probably does what you wanted Get-ChildItem to do.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for the link and the samples of fun. I'll mark my q as a duplicate of the one you pointed to.