# Get-ChildItem -File -Exclude issue

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

### Issue

I wrapped `Get-ChildItem` in a generic function to add checks and be able to re-use it. When combining `-File` with `-Exclude`, the function seems to break even though the same call to `Get-ChildItem` outside of it does work as expected.

### Question

What is going wrong? How can I fix it?

### Related

[Get-ChildItem Exclude and File parameters don't work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43191453/get-childitem-exclude-and-file-parameters-dont-work-together)

### MWE

```
function Get-Object {
  [CmdletBinding ()]
  param (
    [Parameter (
      Position    = 1,
      Mandatory   = $true,
      HelpMessage = "Path to the object"
    )]
    [String]
    $Path,
    [Parameter (
      Position    = 2,
      Mandatory   = $false,
      HelpMessage = "Type of object"
    )]
    [ValidateSet ("All", "File", "Folder")]
    [String]
    $Type = "All",
    [Parameter (
      Position    = 3,
      Mandatory   = $false,
      HelpMessage = "Filter to apply"
    )]
    [String]
    $Filter = "*",
    [Parameter (
      Position    = 4,
      Mandatory   = $false,
      HelpMessage = "Pattern to exclude"
    )]
    [String]
    $Exclude = $null
  )
  begin {
    if (-Not (Test-Path -Path $Path)) {
      Write-Host "$Path does not exists."
      exit 1
    }
    $ObjectType = [ordered]@{
      "All"     = "items"
      "File"    = "files"
      "Folder"  = "folders"
    }
  }
  process {
    # Get files
    switch ($Type) {
      "File"    {
        $Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter $Filter -Exclude $Exclude -File
      }
      "Folder"  {
        $Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter $Filter -Exclude $Exclude -Directory
      }
      default   {
        $Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter $Filter -Exclude $Exclude
      }
    }
    # If no files are found, print hints
    if ($Files.Count -eq 0) {
      if ($Filter -ne "*") {
        Write-Host "No $($ObjectType[$Type]) were found in $Path matching the filter ""$Filter""."
      } elseif ($Exclude) {
        Write-Host "No $($ObjectType[$Type]) corresponding to the criterias were found in $Path."
      } else {
        Write-Host "No $($ObjectType[$Type]) were found in $Path."
      }
      # exit 1
    } else {
      return $Files
    }
  }
}

$Path         = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$RelativePath = "\test"
$AbsolutePath = Join-Path -Path $Path -ChildPath $RelativePath
$Filter       = "*"
$Exclude      = $null

Get-ChildItem -Path $RelativePath -Filter $Filter -Exclude $Exclude -File

Get-ChildItem -Path $AbsolutePath -Filter $Filter -Exclude $Exclude -File

Get-Object -Path $RelativePath -Filter $Filter -Exclude $Exclude -Type "File"

Get-Object -Path $AbsolutePath -Filter $Filter -Exclude $Exclude -Type "File"
```

### Output

```
PS C:\> .\test.ps1


    Directory: C:\test


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       21/09/2018     18:42              0 text.txt
-a----       21/09/2018     18:42              0 text.txt
No files were found in \test.
No files were found in C:\test.
```

PS: Any constructive criticism on syntax/best practices is welcome.

Comment: How does the script break?

Comment: Is my explanation not clear enough? The call to `Get-ChildItem` inside the function, with the exact same parameters as an outside call does not yield any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a known problem as per [this issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6865) on the PowerShell GIT repository.

### Solution

There appear to be a conflict while using `-Filter`, `-Exclude`, and `-File` all at the same time. By removing one or adding `-Recurse`, the function works as expected.

1. `Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter $Filter -File`
2. `Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter $Filter -Exclude $Exclude -File -Recurse`

Obviously this is not optimal and should be considered as a workaround until the issue is fixed.

### Full working example

```
function Get-Object {
  [CmdletBinding ()]
  param (
    [Parameter (
      Position    = 1,
      Mandatory   = $true,
      HelpMessage = "Path to the items"
    )]
    [String]
    $Path,
    [Parameter (
      Position    = 2,
      Mandatory   = $false,
      HelpMessage = "Type of object"
    )]
    [ValidateSet ("All", "File", "Folder")]
    [String]
    $Type = "All",
    [Parameter (
      Position    = 3,
      Mandatory   = $false,
      HelpMessage = "Filter to apply"
    )]
    [String]
    $Filter = "*",
    [Parameter (
      Position    = 4,
      Mandatory   = $false,
      HelpMessage = "Pattern to exclude"
    )]
    [String]
    $Exclude = $null
  )
  begin {
    if (-Not (Test-Path -Path $Path)) {
      Write-Host "$Path does not exists."
      exit 1
    }
    $ObjectType = [ordered]@{
      "All"     = "items"
      "File"    = "files"
      "Folder"  = "folders"
    }
  }
  process {
    # Get files
    switch ($Type) {
      "File"    {
        $Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter $Filter -Exclude $Exclude -File -Recurse
      }
      "Folder"  {
        $Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter $Filter -Exclude $Exclude -Directory
      }
      default   {
        $Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter $Filter -Exclude $Exclude
      }
    }
    # If no files are found, print hints
    if ($Files.Count -eq 0) {
      if ($Filter -ne "*") {
        Write-Host "No $($ObjectType[$Type]) were found in $Path matching the filter ""$Filter""."
      } elseif ($Exclude) {
        Write-Host "No $($ObjectType[$Type]) corresponding to the criterias were found in $Path."
      } else {
        Write-Host "No $($ObjectType[$Type]) were found in $Path."
      }
      # exit 1
    } else {
      return $Files
    }
  }
}

$Path         = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$RelativePath = "\test"
$AbsolutePath = Join-Path -Path $Path -ChildPath $RelativePath
$Filter       = "*"
$Exclude      = $null

Get-ChildItem -Path $RelativePath -Filter $Filter -Exclude $Exclude -File

Get-ChildItem -Path $AbsolutePath -Filter $Filter -Exclude $Exclude -File

Get-Object -Path $RelativePath -Filter $Filter -Exclude $Exclude -Type "File"

Get-Object -Path $AbsolutePath -Filter $Filter -Exclude $Exclude -Type "File"
```

### Output

```
PS C:\> .\test.ps1


    Directory: C:\test


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       21/09/2018     18:42              0 text.txt
-a----       21/09/2018     18:42              0 text.txt
-a----       21/09/2018     18:42              0 text.txt
-a----       21/09/2018     18:42              0 text.txt
```